# Laravel added data to authenticated user is being applied to every query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-10

I'm able to add more data to the authenticated user by using the [Laravel Global Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#global-scopes) what I didn't know is that this forces the data in every relationship with the model User.

My `user` class is something like this:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::addGlobalScope('subscription', function (Builder $builder)
        {
            $builder->with('subscription.lastpayment');
            $builder->with('tickets');
        });
    }
}
```

Which translates to being able to access `auth()->user()->subscription`, `auth()->user()->subscription->lastpayment` and `auth()->user()->tickets`.

But now if I use a model that has a relationship with the `user` model, such as:

```
$tickets = \App\Models\Tickets::with('user')
    ->with('lastmessage')
    ->with('lastmessage.user')
    ->where('subscription_id', auth()->user()->subscription_id)
    ->get();
```

Both `with('user')` and `with('lastmessage.user')` are running the global scope and querying `subscriptions`, `lastpayment` & `tickets` tables.

How can I avoid this? This is performing multiple queries unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using [`withoutGlobalScope()`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#global-scopes) ?

example

```
$tickets = Tickets::withoutGlobalScope('subscription')
    ->with('user')
    ->with('lastmessage')
    ->with('lastmessage.user')
    ->where('subscription_id', auth()->user()->subscription_id)
    ->get();
```

To completely disable specific queries you can pass empty like this

```
Tickets::withoutGlobalScopes()->...
```

---

Edit 01

try with using `without()`

```
$tickets = Tickets::with(['user' => function ($query) {
        $query->without('subscription', 'tickets');
    }])
    ->with(['lastmessage.user' => function ($query) {
        $query->without('subscription', 'tickets');
    }])
    ->where('subscription_id', auth()->user()->subscription_id)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Yes I tried both options, the number of queries remains. Currently Laravel Debugbar shows 23 queries being executed and if I comment the code of `booted()` and run again it shows 14 queries being executed.

Comment: @Linesofcode did you tried like disabling all `Tickets::withoutGlobalScopes()->` and as well as manually one by  one

Comment: and check this runs when you call this function or before hand

Comment: Yes, I tried both solutions. and the problem persists. The `booted` is being run in `with('user')` and `with('lastmessage.user')` everytime.

Comment: Check that the relationships in your models are configured to utilize eager loading (`$this->belongsTo` or `$this->hasMany`) instead of lazy loading (`$this->belongsTo` or `$this->hasMany`). By using eager loading, you can load associated models in a single query, thus avoiding the need for additional queries that may arise from lazy loading.

Comment: Btw, shouldn't `withoutGlobalScopes()` only work if there were global scopes in `Tickets.php` model? Because I'm accessing `Tickets` model in my query. Yes, I have all the relationships using `hasMany` & `hasOne`.

Comment: Now it worked, I completely forgot to do the inner query inside `with`. Also, instead of using `without`, you can just use `with(['user' => function ($query) { $query->withoutGlobalScopes(); }])`